# Finding the Next Due Date for a task

Tags: sql, excel, azure-sql-database, lookup

Good day to you all. Here's my table:

```
EarnDate  |   Id   |    Task    | Employee

9/01/2017 |  1234  | Task1      | Bob  
9/05/2017 |  4313  | Task2      | Jane   
9/07/2017 |  4144  | Task3      | Drew    
9/21/2017 |  2341  | Task4      | Tyler  
9/21/2017 |  2342  | Task5      | Jim
```

At my work, we have a series of tasks that have to be done every 90 days. This data is being saved to a database in SQL. Within Excel, I create reports that how when employees have to do their inspection.

My report that I'm trying to create displays the following:

```
Name | Task1Due   | Task2Due   | Task3Due   |   Task4Due | Task5Due  
Bob  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017 |01/01/2017  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017  
Sue  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017 |01/01/2017  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017  
Tim  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017 |01/01/2017  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017  
Rob  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017 |01/01/2017  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017  
Jim  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017 |01/01/2017  | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2017
```

Since our main table is over 2000 records, I've created a SQL view for every employee, then imported that view into a table in Excel. What I'm having trouble with, is finding a formula that searches that table, and comes back with the their last task date + 90 days.  This table is convenient for employees so that they don't have to go into the log themselves and do the math.

Steps for this formula:

1. On selected column (name), search table. [I'm assuming this is the LOOKUP]
2. When table is found, search for the task [Task 1, for example]
3. Find the date in employee table and then add 90.
4. Display date.

Maybe it's late in the day, maybe I'm a noob at Excel. Thank you all for your help. Have an awesome day.

-B

Comment: what have your tried so far in terms of formulas or methods on your own?  Can someone have more or less than 5 tasks?

Comment: Yes, There's over 25 tasks for 50 employees.                                                                                      I've used pivot tables to calculate how many times they've done a certain task, and then on a different sheet used the LOOKUP and SUM functions to calculate that data.                                                                                                      I've done a  LOOKUP and add 90 to the date. Which works well it's just one row, because there's multiple rows I have seemed to figure out how to get excel look at the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this formula:

=INDIRECT("TypeSheet & Column Letter" & MATCH('User Name','Name_Column',0)+ 'difference between start row reference and top',TRUE) + 90

Make sure these cells are formatted as short dates.

"type sheet & Column letter"--- Ex) "Sheet1!A" This refers to the date column (Quotes are necessary)

'User Name'---- This can reference a cell with the users name or you can manually type in with quotes

'Name Column'--- this refers to the range that the users name can be found

'difference between start row reference and top'--using match requires that you add x amount of rows to the match function from where the range starts to where row 1 is Ex) range is A5:A10, add 4 to the match function

Comment: Thanks Tony! I'll give this a try today.

Comment: You're welcome. There are a couple ways of doing this depending on your formattinf. If it doesnt work please let me know

Comment: Looking at this closer, you may have to use that formula multiple times in an if statement which compares in one row to another date in another row in the next and returns the largest date.

Comment: So far, I havent had much success. Here's the formula I'm using to find expiratio n dates for Bob   =INDIRECT("Database!A" & MATCH('Bob','Employee',0)+ 'A2:A19',TRUE) + 90